# PyMuPDF insert image at bottom

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, pdf-generation, pymupdf

I'm trying to read a PDF and insert an image at bottom(Footer) of each page in PDF. I've tried with PyMuPDF library.

Problem: Whatever the `Rect` (height, width) I give, it doesn't appear in the bottom, image keeps appearing only on the top half of the page (PDF page).

My code:

```
from fitz import fitz, Rect

doc = fitz.open("test_pdf2.pdf")

def add_footer(pdf):
    img = open("footer4.jpg", "rb").read()
    rect = Rect(0, 0, 570, 1230)

    for i in range(0, pdf.pageCount):
        page = pdf[i]
        if not page._isWrapped:
            page._wrapContents()
        page.insertImage(rect, stream=img)

add_footer(doc)
doc.save('test_pdf5.pdf')
```

Processed_image with footer image in the middle of the page:
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/HK9mm.png

Footer image:
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRQYE.jpg

Please help!

Please let me know if this can be achieved by using any other library.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this, if yes, could you please post the answer?

Comment: @BigDataGeek Yup, fortunately I was able to figure-out. Posted the same in the answers section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After doing little trial and error I was able to figure out the problem. I was missing out on proper dimensions of Rect, I had to give 0.85*h in second parameter.
below is the code:

```
from fitz import fitz, Rect

doc = fitz.open("test_pdf2.pdf")
w = 595
h = 842

def add_footer(pdf):
    img = open("footer4.jpg", "rb").read()
    rect = fitz.Rect(0, 0.85*h, w, h)

    for i in range(0, pdf.pageCount):
        page = pdf[i]
        if not page._isWrapped:
            page._wrapContents()
        page.insertImage(rect, stream=img)

add_footer(doc)
doc.save('test_pdf5.pdf')
```

Answer (score 2):

Some pages internally change the standard PDF geometry (which uses the bottom-left page point as (0, 0)) to something else, **and at the same time do not encapsulate** this doing properly as they should.

If you suspect this, use PyMuPDF methods to encapsulate the current page `/Contents` **before** you insert your items (text, images, etc.).

The easiest way is `Page._wrapContents()` which is also the friendly way to keep incremental PDF saves small. The **MuPDF** provided `Page.cleanContents()` does this and a lot more cleaning stuff, but bloats the incremental save delta, if this is a concern.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but it wasn't about encapsulation. I figured out the answer. posted the same.

Answer (score 1):

use:

wrapContents – Page.wrap_contents()

https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/znames.html?highlight=wrapContents

---

```
from fitz import fitz, Rect

doc = fitz.open("example.pdf")
w = 250
h = 400

def add_footer(pdf):
    img = open("firmaJG.png", "rb").read()
    rect = fitz.Rect(0, 0.85*h, w, h)

    for i in range(0, pdf.pageCount):
        page = pdf[i]
        if not page._isWrapped:
            page.wrap_contents()
        page.insertImage(rect, stream=img)

add_footer(doc)
doc.save('test_pdf5.pdf')
```